# How to nest kusto query based on grouped value

Tags: nested, max, azure-data-explorer

I have a table that contains items and their changing prices depending on the dates.

```
gold 12-jan $400
gold 15-jan $440
silv 13-jan $100
silv 10-jan $090
```

I need a kusto query that can fetch me the item and its latest price.
so output be:

```
gold 15-jan $440
silv 13-jan $100
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [arg_max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction)

For example:

```
T | summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by item
```